# I want to check the whitespace of a string and want to print the first character just after the whitespace to a upper case letter

Tags: java

I want to check the whitespace of a string and want to print the first character just after the whitespace to a upper case letter.

e:g--> Input- `I am in trouble`

output should be like this--> `I Am In Trouble`.

1. I am able to catch he whitespace (no matter how many are they) in the string but not able to change the first character just after space to an uppercase letter.
2. and how to accommodate the changed first character after whitespaces(which is now a upper case letter) to the original **str** . So that when i print i'll find the output as mentioned above.

i have shared whatever i have tried,plese have a  look and guide me through.

```
public class CatchSpace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str="I am in trouble";

        char[] arr=str.toCharArray();

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

            if(arr[i]==' '){

                //str.charAt(i+1);
                //Character.toUpperCase(i+1);
                char c=arr[i+1];    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, but you need to store the new uppercase character back into your array:

```
    String str = "I am in trouble";
    char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == ' ') {
            //str.charAt(i+1);
            //Character.toUpperCase(i+1);
            char c = arr[i + 1];
            arr[i+1] = Character.toUpperCase(c); // like this;
        }
    }
```

Comment: in case the last character is whitespace, you may want to do bound checking or at least restrict to arr.length - 1

Comment: Thaaannnnkksss a lot...  i was really hunting my head for this.. Meets the requirement..:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache Commons Lang instead a direct Java API.

Simply split the string by the whitespace and then use `StringUtils.capitalize` method for each of the tokens and then concatenate (i.e. using Guava collections).

I'm attaching the example below (an extreme version using Guava and Commons Lang):

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.*;
import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.*;

public class TestCapitalize {

    private Joiner joiner = Joiner.on(" "); 

    private Function<String, String> fCapitalize = new Function<String, String>() {
        public String apply(String s) {
            return capitalize(s);
        }
    };

    public String capitalizeAll() {        
        String str = "I am in trouble";
        List<String> tokens = newArrayList(split(str, " "));
        List<String> capitalized = transform(tokens, fCapitalize);
        return joiner.join(capitalized);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "testy testy testy";
        char arr[] = str.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++){
            //we go until length-1 so we don't get an out of bounds exception if the last character of the string is a whitespace
            if(Character.isWhitespace(arr[i])){
                arr[i+1] = Character.toUpperCase(arr[i+1]);
            }
        }
        str = arr.toString();
```

This would do it. The only thing this wouldn't do is capitalize the first letter of the array if it isn't already capitalized. If you want that, it will only take a simple modification.

```
String str = "testy testy testy";
        char arr[] = str.toCharArray();
        arr[0] = Character.toUpperCase(arr[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++){
            //we go until length-1 so we don't get an out of bounds exception if the last character of the string is a whitespace
            if(Character.isWhitespace(arr[i])){
                arr[i+1] = Character.toUpperCase(arr[i+1]);
            }
        }
        str = arr.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, using regex:

```
String str = "testy testy testy";
char arr[] = str.toCharArray();
// set first char to UpperCase
arr[0] = Character.toUpperCase(arr[0]);
// pattern is set to match any space char followed by lowercase char
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(" [a-z]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
     arr[i+1] =  Character.toUpperCase(arr[m.start()+1]);
}
// Turn the array back to a string
str = arr.toString();
```

It's similar to Lighthat's answer but this way, it will only apply the toUpperCase on lowercase characters and you won't risk to have any IndexOutOfBoundException